# How can l colorize an RGB image with blue color?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have the following image that l would like to colorize with blue color.

Image input :
[image: inputs]

Expected output :
[image: Expected_output]

Is there any skimage or opencv tool that allows to do this kind of operation  ?

Thank you

Comment: Your expected output is rather washed out. Do you really want that, or would you like to keep a bit more contrast and detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the desired effect by applying a transparent overlay. I roughly figured out the color (sky blue) by trial-and-error. It can be changed to any color possible.

In OpenCV you can use the `cv2..addWeighted()` for this purpose

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = 'C:/Users/Desktop/city.jpg'
im = cv2.imread(path, 1)

blue = np.zeros_like(im)
blue[:] = (255, 200, 0)     #<--- Change here
cv2.imshow('blue.jpg', blue)
```

[image]

```
val = 0.75
fin = cv2.addWeighted(blue, val, im, 1 - val, 0)
cv2.imshow('Transparent_image', fin)
```

[image]

As mentioned by @vasia setting the red and green pixels to `0` does not produce the desired effect. This is what I get as a result:

[image]

**UPDATE**

@MarkSetchell's comment got me thinking and this is the result of that:

[image]

So what did I do?

I merged three channels:

1. An array of values 255 in the blue channel
2. Grayscale of the original image in the green channel
3. An array of values 0 in the red channel

Thanks Mark!!

Comment: I think it might come out better if you grayscale the original before adding the weighted layer... maybe :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes you are right check out  the update !!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question exactly, you can just set the other channels to 0. You might want to set them a bit higher than that or things end up a bit dark, but here you go:

```
img = cv2.imread(your_image)
img[:, :, 1] = 0  # (or 20)
img[:, :, 2] = 0

cv2.namedWindow("test")

while True:
    cv2.imshow("test", a)
    ch = cv2.waitKey & 0xFF
    if ch == ord('q'):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here's an example:

[image: Original Image]
[image: Blue Cage]

Comment: The problem with doing it this way is the image ends up way too dark.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by blending two images together, create one that is just your blue image, and blend it together with an alpha of your choosing:

[here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) is the OpenCV tutorial on how to do that.

You can see how this can affect your images in more detail on this [blog post](http://eric-yuan.me/poisson-blending/)

Answer (score 0):

A typical bitmap image is a two-dimensional grid of pixels, where each pixel is a group of three integers ranging from 0 to 255, representing red, green, and blue. If you want to view only the blue channel of an image, you could create a new image from the pixels in your original image, and set the red and green pixel values to 0 for each pixel, leaving only blue.

Comment: setting the red and green pixels to 0 does not produce the desired effect!!! Have you tried it?

Comment: I actually thought this would work too but when I tried it out it didn't. So I had to think of something else. This is how we learn ! Nice try though!

Answer (score 0):

Pure `numpy` solution

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io

def blend(a, b, alpha):
    return (alpha * a + (1 - alpha) * b).astype(np.uint8)

def luma(img):
    rgb_to_luma = np.array([0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722]) # BT.709
    return np.repeat((img * rgb_to_luma).sum(axis=-1).astype(np.uint8), 3).reshape(img.shape)

BGCOLOR = np.array([1, 174, 242])

img = skimage.io.imread('city.jpg')
bg = np.ones_like(img) * BGCOLOR

skimage.io.imsave('blue.png', blend(luma(img), bg, 0.2))
```

[image]